# How to handle retrieving user asynchronously from Firestore in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous

I have a Swift app that uses Firebase for user handling. I also have a User class with a singleton for the current user. I'm trying to set this singleton in the Scene Delegate before anything happens with the ViewControllers in the app, but I am having trouble with the asynchronous retrieval of data from Firestore. In my home view controller, I attempt to set the text of a label with the name of the current user, but I get the error that there is no current user, so it hasn't been set when viewDidLoad is called. My Scene Delegate looks like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {

            print("user is logged in")
            print("current user uid: @!", currentUser.uid)


            UserService.getUserData(uid: currentUser.uid) { (data) in
                if let data = data {
                    print(data.keys)
                    let myUser = User(uid: currentUser.uid, data: data)
                    User.setCurrent(myUser)
                    print("User was set")

                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)

                    if let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {

                        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                    }

                } else {
                    print("Error retrieving user data")
                }
            }

        } else {

            let initialViewController = UIStoryboard.initalViewController(for: .login)
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }

    }
```

My getUserData function:

```
static func getUserData(uid: String, _ completion: @escaping (_ data: [String: Any]?) -> Void ) {
        print("getUserData called")
        let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(Constants.Firestore.Collections.users)
        let userDocRef = userRef.document(uid)

        userDocRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            guard let document = document, document.exists else {
                print("document does not exist")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            print("code is here")
            completion(document.data())
        }
    }
```

And my HomeVC viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        availabilitySwitch.isOn = false
        print("Home view loaded")
        let first = User.current.firstName
        welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome Back, " + first + "!"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }
```

Any idea on how to get the user data before this is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a property in `HomeVC`

```
var username = ""
```

and display the value of the property in `viewDidLoad` if it's not empty.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    availabilitySwitch.isOn = false
    print("Home view loaded")
    if !username.isEmpty {
        welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome Back, " + username + "!"
    }
}
```

In `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo` assign the username after instantiating the view controller

```
...
UserService.getUserData(uid: currentUser.uid) { (data) in
    if let data = data {
        print(data.keys)
        let myUser = User(uid: currentUser.uid, data: data)
        User.setCurrent(myUser)
        print("User was set")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)

        if let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
            (initialViewController as! HomeVC).username = myUser.firstName
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

    } else {
        print("Error retrieving user data")
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Just tried it, gives me the error, "could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' to 'Myapp.HomeVC'" at the line:
`(initialViewController as! HomeVC).username = myUser.firstName`

Comment: This was just a guess. You have to get the instance of the home view controller. This depends on the design and there is no information in the code. Maybe `((initialViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! HomeVC)`

Comment: Now it worked thank you! The only problem is, the home view flashes with the [User] placeholder before it is replaced by the user's first name. Any idea how to wait to load the view until the first name is loaded in?